# Creating an object in Python with lots of long arguments

Tags: python, python-2.x, pyqt

See the proposed changes in [this Pull Request](https://github.com/Freeseer/freeseer/pull/533/files#diff-1c2ac91deea642c6d24c522c834b474fR61) under `def add_talk`.

```
date = self.talkDetailsWidget.dateEdit.date()
time = self.talkDetailsWidget.timeEdit.time()
presentation = Presentation(
    unicode(self.talkDetailsWidget.titleLineEdit.text()).strip(),
    unicode(self.talkDetailsWidget.presenterLineEdit.text()).strip(),
    unicode(self.talkDetailsWidget.descriptionTextEdit.toPlainText()).strip(),
    unicode(self.talkDetailsWidget.categoryLineEdit.text()).strip(),
    unicode(self.talkDetailsWidget.eventLineEdit.text()).strip(),
    unicode(self.talkDetailsWidget.roomLineEdit.text()).strip(),
    unicode(date.toString(Qt.ISODate)),
    unicode(time.toString(Qt.ISODate)))
```

There's a lot of boilerplate code (e.g. `unicode()`, `seld.talkDetailsWidget`, `text()`, `strip()`, etc.) How could you reduce that and still have the code be easy to understand?

My thinking is if something along the lines of this were possible:

```
map(str.strip,
    map(unicode, 
        map(QLineEdit.text,
            map(self.talkDetailsWidget, fields))))
```

Comment: Had you used Python 3.4, you could have used `functools.singledispatch` to create an overload of `Presentation.__init__` taking a `TalkDetailsWidget` parameter.

Comment: @Morwenn that's good to know! We want to move over to Python3, but like most other projects, we need our dependencies to be compatible first. We should look into it again, maybe we're much closer now than the last time we checked.

Comment: Moving to Python 3 can be pretty tricky, but it's worth. I would say that the biggest problem is the current lack of some libraries (I'm looking at you, PIL).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your [`TalkDetailsWidget`](https://github.com/Freeseer/freeseer/blob/54cbe80d577b2fe1632679426f99435da5fafa28/src/freeseer/frontend/talkeditor/TalkDetailsWidget.py) is underdeveloped, I think.  You could say that you have a view but no model, and that is causing you problems.

You want to be able to write

```
talk = self.talkDetailsWidget
presentation = Presentation(title=talk.title,
                          speaker=talk.presenter,   # ← Why the inconsistent vocabulary?
                      description=talk.description,
                         category=talk.category,
                            event=talk.event,
                             room=talk.room,
                             date=unicode(talk.date.toString(Qt.ISODate)),
                             time=unicode(talk.time.toString(Qt.ISOTime)))
```

Therefore, you'll need to implement new properties in `TalkDetailsWidget`.  To avoid copy-and-paste programming in `TalkDetailsWidget`, I suggest writing those getters using metaprogramming.

```
class TalkDetailsWidget(QWidget):
    …

    def _field_reader(field, method='text'):
        return property(fget=lambda self: unicode(getattr(getattr(self, field), method)()).strip(),
                        doc="Returns a Unicode string from the %s field with spaces stripped from each end" % (field))

    title       = _field_reader('titleLineEdit')
    presenter   = _field_reader('presenterLineEdit')
    description = _field_reader('descriptionTextEdit', method='toPlainText')
    category    = _field_reader('categoryLineEdit')
    event       = _field_reader('eventLineEdit')
    room        = _field_reader('roomLineEdit')

    @property
    def date(self):
        self.dateEdit.date()

    @property
    def time(self):
        self.timeEdit.time()
```

Comment: Unrelated note - your code violates PEP8 with aligning lines and 80 characters per columns limit.

Comment: @RuslanOsipov I am aware that it violates PEP8. The `fget` parameter could use a proper function instead of a lambda. Not sure what to do about the docstring. As for the unusual alignment by the equals sign for the arguments of `Presentation`, I think the violation aids readability.

Comment: Makes sense. The docstring can be wrapped in `("line 1"\n"line 2")`, but it's not important in the context.